# Cache Data Using Lru Cache In Android

Tags: android, caching, garbage-collection, android-lru-cache

I am trying to cache some data using `LruCache` in android, say like I have

```
LruCache<String, SomeDataClass>
```

And SomeDataClass like

```
data class SomeDataClass(val data: Any)
```

My doubt is if am pushing some data to the `cache` and by the time cache is full, so `LruCache` will automatically evict the least used item and push the new one.

1. Is the evicted item will be garbage collected?
2. Is it safe to use the
   already fetched item that was evicted now from the cache?

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Why don't you persist this data?